# Converting Excel Formula to VBA Code With Dynamic Reference

Tags: vba, excel

I have in my code variable named `MyCol` that gets the number of the column by month that was selected in a userform. for example October is in column U and November is in column V. I have a formula that I recorded and the month that was chosen is part of it but it is a problem because RC format is with specific reference and my variable is an integer.

I want that the formula will be dynamic.

This is the formula (column U means month that was chosen):

> =IFNA(IF(VLOOKUP(AA2,sheet1!F:F,1,0)=AA2,U2,0),0)

That is the relavant part of the code:

```
Dim MonthName As String
Dim myCol As Integer

MonthName = ListMonth.Value

With MainWB.Worksheets("sheet2")
    .Activate
    .Range("L1:W1").Find(MonthName, , xlValues, xlWhole).Activate
End With
ActiveCell.Select
myCol = Selection.Column
Range("AB2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IFNA(IF(VLOOKUP(RC[-1],sheet1!C[-22],1,0)=RC[-1],RC[" & myCol & "],0),0)"
Range("AB2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("AB2:AB" & MLR), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your :

```
Range("AB2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IFNA(IF(VLOOKUP(RC[-1],sheet1!C[-22],1,0)=RC[-1],RC[" & myCol & "],0),0)"
```

With:

```
Range("AB2").FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=IFNA(IF(VLOOKUP(RC[-1],sheet1!C[-22],1,0)=RC[-1],RC[-" & Range("AB2").Column - myCol & "],0),0)"
```

---

**However**, if you want to make your code run faster, and also avoid all the unecessary `Activate`, `ActiveCell`, `Select`, try the code below:

```
Dim FindRng As Range

MonthName = ListMonth.Value

With MainWB.Worksheets("sheet2")
    Set FindRng = .Range("L1:W1").Find(MonthName, , xlValues, xlWhole)
End With

If Not FindRng Is Nothing Then
    myCol = FindRng.Column
Else ' find was not successful finding the month name
    MsgBox "Unable to find " & MonthName, vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If

Range("AB2").FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=IFNA(IF(VLOOKUP(RC[-1],sheet1!C[-22],1,0)=RC[-1],RC[-" & Range("AB2").Column - myCol & "],0),0)"
```

Comment: - oops I flagged this because I mistakenly thought the OP was the same person who posted the answer.  I'm sure the mod who sees the flag will ignore it.  Sry, instead I'll +1.  :)